# Is there a way to avoid sustaining any knockback?

Tags: risk-of-rain-2

Is there any way to mitigate knock-back taken so you do not move at all? I would like to not be moved at all whenever taking damage, in specific regards to how Bustling Fungus works.

Comment: The advice I've heard is that it's basically a useless item unless you're an engineer with stationary turrets.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question but yeah fungus isn't as good as it seems, especially later when you get one-hit by pretty much everything.

Comment: I know. I plan on mixing it with Aegis and Horn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no item in Risk of Rain 2 that reduces or affects knockback directly in any way.

However, if you don't take damage then you can't be knocked back, so taking a few stacks of Tougher Times might help to mitigate knockback a *little bit* since you'll be blocking some hits, and therefore not being knocked back by them.

Comment: The answer I expected but hoped not to see :(